# How do I fix this Nginx configuration to properly proxy WebSocket requests instead of returning a 301?

Tags: nginx, proxy, websocket, config, proxypass

Nginx noob. Trying to configure Nginx to act as an SSL proxy server in front of another web server running at `http://localhost:8082`.  That is, I want all requests to `http://localhost` to be redirected to `https://localhost`.  That part is working just fine.

Problem is, the app on port 8082 also uses WebSocket connections at `ws://localhost:8082/public-api/repossession-requests-socket`.  I'm trying to redirect any connections to `ws://localhost/public-api/repossession-requests-socket` to `wss://localhost/public-api/repossession-requests-socket` and have Nginx proxy those WebSocket requests to `ws://localhost:8082/public-api/repossession-requests-socket`.

Instead, the WebSocket connections are failing because Nginx is returning a 301 for *both* `ws://localhost/public-api/repossession-requests-socket` & `wss://localhost/public-api/repossession-requests-socket`.  My configuration is below; I'm using the Docker image `nginx:alpine` in my tests (`$PWD` is mapped to `/app`).

How do I need to change this so that I no longer see 301s?

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        server_name localhost;

        ssl_certificate /app/docker/public.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /app/docker/private.pem;

        ssl on;
        ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /app/access-443.log;

        location / {
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

          proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
          proxy_read_timeout 90;

          proxy_redirect http://localhost:8082 https://localhost;
        }
        location /public-api/repossession-requests-socket/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.  The trailing slash on the end of the `location` stanza.

`location /public-api/repossession-reqeuests-socket/` should have been `location /public-api/repossession-reqeuests-socket`.